# Social Sharing Working Android but not ios

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

so i was coding a cordova app for android and ios. i added social sharing feature to a page. It works great for android but on ios it just gives blank option when i try to share.

here is the code

```
    var srcDesc = "somesite.com/article-desc-"+x+"_";

            $$('#Socilalsharing').append('<div class="item-content"><div class="item-media"></div><div class="item-inner" style="text-align: center;"><div class="item-title label" style="width: 20%;" onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share("Share Test", null,null, \''+srcDesc+'\')"><i class="fa fa-share-alt-square" style="font-size: 45px;"></i><p><b>share</b></p></div></div></div>');
```

any idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

what's the error message your getting when you click on this ? 
Also did you check the plugins page do you have the (socialSharing.h).h and (socialSharing.m).m files which get generated when you download the plugin from npm.

Comment: no error msg as this is working on andoid. just it says this may not work on simulator (ios)

Comment: have you added this plugin in your config files ?